# Как согласовать предложение?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Он, не приученный ни к умственному, ни к физическому труду,  только спал и ел,  работать не мог, хотя был вовсе не глупым человеком,

Answer (score 3):

А что здесь согласовывать? Всё согласовано верно.

Comment: Если Вы имеете в виду "...был вовсе не глупый человек", то современная норма как раз больше с творит. падежом. Если углубляться и говорить о постоянном признаке, можно и с именительным. Так что всё в порядке

Answer (score 0):

Он не был приучен...

или

Не приученный к умственному и физическому труду он только спал и ел, работать не хотел)...

Comment: Зачем?_________